# single model connected to multiple views on multiple dialogs, not updating

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt4

two independent forms that are connected to the same model. as i understand how model view is suppose to work, that all views connected to the model should present the data in the model. but this is not the case. please see the code attached.

```
class Model(QStringListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        data = QStringList()
        data << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five"
        self.setStringList(data)


class Form_2(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.combo = QListView()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form_1(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.listView = QListView()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)
        self.form2_button = QPushButton("Open Form_2")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listView)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.form2_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(self.form2_button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.form_2)

    def form_2(self):
        self.ft = Form_2()
        self.ft.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form_1()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to ccc.larc for answering my question. you basically need to pass the same instance of the model to which ever form you want it to use.

```
class Model(QStringListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        data = QStringList()
        data << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five"
        self.setStringList(data)


class Form_2(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(Form_2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = model
        self.combo = QListView()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form_1(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.listView = QListView()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)
        self.form2_button = QPushButton("Open Form_2")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listView)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.form2_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(self.form2_button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.form_2)

    def form_2(self):
        self.ft = Form_2(self.model)
        self.ft.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form_1()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```